# UPDATE with NOT LIKE Operator

Tags: ms-access

```
UPDATE Table
    SET Table.[Field] = 'DUMMY' WHERE Table.[Acct Numb] not like 
( '*01'. '*03'. '*04'. '*07'. '*08'. '*09');
```

Can I use NOT LIKE operator using update query? I am using MS ACCESS for execution of this query.

Thanks

Comment: I removed the "sql-server" tag and added "access" because you explicitly say Access in the OP.  There is a difference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not like`, but not with a list:

```
UPDATE Table
    SET Table.[Field] = 'DUMMY'
    WHERE Table.[Acct Numb] not like '*01' and
          Table.[Acct Numb] not like '*03' and
          Table.[Acct Numb] not like '*04' and
          Table.[Acct Numb] not like '*07' and
          Table.[Acct Numb] not like '*08' and
          Table.[Acct Numb] not like '*09';
```

You can also right this as:

```
update table
     SET Table.[Field] = 'DUMMY'
     where right(Table.[Acct Numb], 2) not in ( '01'. '03'. '04'. '07'. '08'. '09')
```

Comment: @Phill I guess we can propose using Biro and piece of paper as an optimisation method then.

Comment: Or perhaps for brevity NOT LIKE *0[134789]

Comment: @AlexK haha I was just looking at the wild-card reference to see if that was possible because I had an inkling that it was. http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HP005188185.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Based on the MS reference for access, and as @Alex K suggested

http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HP005188185.aspx

You should be able to do:

```
UPDATE Table
    SET Table.[Field] = 'DUMMY'
    WHERE Table.[Acct Numb] not like '*0[134789]'
```